# Minimum hardware requirement for android studio in 2021/022?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, mobile-development

I've laptop having specification as

1. inten i5 10th gen
2. 8GB RAM
3. 256 SSD
4. nvidia mx250

Can I run android studio properly/smoothly ??

Comment: 16 gb recommended if using emulator . This is not a question for stackoverflow .

Answer (score 0):

Yup with the configuration you have you will be able to run the android studio very easily, but I will suggest to expand your RAM from 8 to 16 because then it will give you certain advantage while using the AVD.

And yaa make sure that you are storing the android studio in your SSD.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will work well, but If you are using the emulator, it is preferable that the RAM be 16GB, but that does not mean that it will not work on 8GB :)

Also, check the requirements of Android studio on its official website

https://developer.android.com/studio

- Windows

64-bit Microsoft® Windows® 8/10

x86_64 CPU architecture; 2nd generation Intel Core or newer, or AMD CPU with support for a Windows Hypervisor

8 GB RAM or more

8 GB of available disk space minimum (IDE + Android SDK + Android Emulator)

1280 x 800 minimum screen resolution